# angular ng-file-upload iPad mini error with multiple upload areas

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have multiple drag&drop areas as below:

Please note the div has a flip animation done in CSS, on hover.

```
<div class="row">


<div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="box-flip-container horizontal dimension320x50">
                <div class="flipper height-25" ngf-drop ngf-select ngf-change="upload($files, '320x50')" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-allow-dir="false" accept="image/*" ngf-drag-over-class="dragover">
                    <div class="banner-box flip-front">
                        <div class="sponsor-banner-text relative-box height-25">320x50
                            <img ngf-src="banners.medium2" ngf-background="banners.medium2" alt="" class="flip-img height-25" ng-if="banners.medium2">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.flip-front -->
                    <div class="flip-back horizontal banner-box sponsor-banner-text height-25" ng-class="{'app-box-shadow': expandText320}">
                        <span ng-class="{'hidden': expandText320}">back flip</span><span ng-class="{'hidden': !expandText320}">lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>


                    </div>
                    <!-- /.flip-back horizontal -->
                    <div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.flipper -->
                <a href="" class="default-btn more-info-plus" ng-click="expandText320 = !expandText320"><i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus-square':expandText320, 'fa-plus-square': !expandText320}"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-flip-container horizontal -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-xs-5 one box-->


        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad-left-right">
            <div class="box-flip-container horizontal dimension120x60">
                <div class="flipper height-25" ngf-drop ngf-select ngf-change="upload($files, '120x60')" ngf-drag-over-class="dragover" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-allow-dir="false" accept="image/*">
                    <div class="banner-box flip-front">
                        <div class="sponsor-banner-text relative-box height-25">120x60
                            <img ngf-src="banners.small1" ngf-background="banners.small1" alt="" class="flip-img height-25" ng-if="banners.small1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.flip-front -->
                    <div class="flip-back horizontal banner-box sponsor-banner-text height-25" ng-class="{'app-box-shadow': expandText12060}"><span ng-class="{'hidden': expandText12060}">back flip</span><span ng-class="{'hidden': !expandText12060}">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.flip-back horizontal -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.flipper -->
                <div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>
                <a href="" class="default-btn more-info-plus" ng-click="expandText12060 = !expandText12060"><i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus-square':expandText12060, 'fa-plus-square': !expandText12060}"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-flip-container horizontal -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-xs-2 one box-->


        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="box-flip-container horizontal dimension320x50 float-right-medium">
                <div class="flipper height-25" ngf-drop ngf-select ngf-change="upload($files, '300x50')" ngf-drag-over-class="dragover" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-allow-dir="false" accept="image/*">
                    <div class="banner-box flip-front">
                        <div class="relative-box sponsor-banner-text height-25">300x50
                            <img ngf-src="banners.medium1" ngf-background="banners.medium1" alt="" class="flip-img height-25" ng-if="banners.medium1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.flip-front -->
                    <div class="flip-back horizontal banner-box sponsor-banner-text height-25" ng-class="{'app-box-shadow': expandText300}"><span ng-class="{'hidden': expandText300}">back flip</span><span ng-class="{'hidden': !expandText300}">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.flip-back horizontal -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.flipper -->
                <div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>
                <a href="" class="default-btn more-info-plus" ng-click="expandText300 = !expandText300"><i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus-square':expandText300, 'fa-plus-square': !expandText300}"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-flip-container horizontal -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-xs-5 one box-->


    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

CSS:

```
    /*********************
    * flip animation
    *********************/

    .flipper {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        &.dragover {
            outline: 2px dashed $active-link-color;
        }
    }

    .flip-front,
    .flip-back {
        @include transition-property(transform);
        @include transition-duration(0.4s);
        @include transition-timing-function(ease-in);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .flip-back {
        z-index: 2;
        &.horizontal {
            @include transform(rotateY(-180deg));
        }
        &.vertical {
            @include transform(rotateX(-180deg));
        }
    }

.box-flip-container {
    position: relative;
    &.horizontal {
        &:hover {
            .flip-front {
                @include transform(rotateY(-180deg));
            }
            .flip-back {
                @include transform(rotateY(0deg));
            }
        }
    }
    &.vertical {
        &:hover {
            .flip-front {
                @include transform(rotateX(-180deg));
            }
            .flip-back {
                @include transform(rotateX(0deg));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In iPad mini/Safari, if I upload on one of the areas, the file uploads. BUT if I click on another area and choose a photo, the previous area uploads again. I have to click again on the new area to be able to upload the file where I want. I have to double click on the new area in order to have the file upload on that area, or sometimes I have to click multiple times.

In iPad mini/Chrome: I need to upload 2 times the photo on the same area so you can see it. If you upload it once, it doesn't show.

I'm thinking this might be an error with the hover states, as somehow if you click once on a div, the image flips and if you click on another div, that initial div flips back and the new one doesn't flip at all... but how can I fix this?

Could you please advise if this is a plugin error or is it something in my code?

Thank you and best regards,
Mihai